# Mono c# SoundPlayer doesn't work

Tags: c#, mono, raspberry-pi, raspbian, playsound

I try to play a sound from a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian installed. I have mono installed. I tested it on Windows, and it runs well. But when running it on Raspbian. I don't get any error message and no sound either.

```
public void PlaySound()
{
    try
    {
        using (var file = new FileStream("example.wav",
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            var player = new SoundPlayer(file);
            player.PlaySync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sound failed to play");
    }
}
```

Mono version

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-10)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
TLS:           __thread
SIGSEGV:       normal
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  armel,vfp+hard
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug
LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
GC:            sgen
```

Comment: Report this issue to Mono and see if they can show you how to debug.

Comment: Mono's non-Windows sound is based upon Alsa (`alsa-utils`) so if that is not working properly Mono will not either... There are lots of blog posts about setup and testing of Alsa on Rassies, i.e.  http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/01/sound-configuration-on-raspberry-pi-with-alsa/